# how to install nmap in docker's ubuntu

Tags: docker

is it possible to install `nmap` in docker's ubuntu? I am install like this in kubernetes pod:

```
root@flink-taskmanager-54d85f57c7-wd2nb:/opt/flink# apt-get install nmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nmap
```

Comment: try updaing the apt repository, and then installing or try installing from source(tar) or use the nmap docker image possibly the base image would be ubuntu.

Comment: Yes,it works.@Rahulroy

Comment: how did it work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this first in the kubernetes pod:

```
apt-get update
```

then install nmap:

```
apt-get install nmap -y
```

it would install nmap success.hope this help for you.